# JToken Array to Data Table C#

Tags: c#, json, datatable

I have a JSON result with the following structure:

```
{
"property1":1,
"property2":[[1,"A"],[2,"B"],[3,"C"],...] // Possible to get >10000 values
}
```

Using the above JSON data format, I am only interested to get the array values from the **property2** which contains an array of array values and convert it to data table.

The above JSON result is coming from an external WEB API and here is what I have currently:

```
var jsonResponse = API.RetrieveData();
JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonResponse);           
JToken[] A = json["property2"].ToArray();
```

Logically, I can loop on the elements of Array [] A column by column and add it to the predesigned data table. My problem is that, upon using this, the performance will be affected as in most cases, the data that will be retrieved from the API is > 10000 values.

Is there any specific way to convert this kind of JSON Format to DataTable in c# with the most efficient way?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have Better and Fast approach for You

**Step 1**

Create a class that is similar to json structure

```
public class JsonClass
{
   public string property1 { get ; set; }
   public List<Dictionary<int,string>> property2 { get ; set; }
}
```

**Step 2**

Use [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/) and deserialize json input to json match class

```
JsonClass jsonClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonClass>(jsonInputString);
```

**Step 3**

if you are using [WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/) just use

```
datatable.ItemSource = jsonClass ;
```

if you are using [Winform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/) then use [BindingSource Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/data-binding-and-windows-forms)

```
BindingSource binding = new BindingSource();
binding.DataSource = jsonClass;
datatable.DataSource = binding;
```

**Result might be**

```
property1 | property2
---------------------------------------
"A"       |  Collection
```

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for this, I got a quick question, what if the property2 is no longer a key-value pair, like it has 25 columns or data in it? I tried public Array []property2 { get; set; } but no luck. Also datatable source should be from property2 only. Appreciate your help!

Comment: If it has 25 columns or what ever it is just use List<string> .any json array is converted to a collection it can be collection of strings or collection of nested arrays or much more complicated array.

Comment: Instead of array use collection like List<T>

Comment: If you only need property2 in datatable make an internal methed like get and return property2 collection no whole class which is included property1

Comment: public ArrayList []data { get; set; } works now, the only remaining problem is to convert the property2 which is of typeof ArrayList to DataTable without loop.

Comment: If you are using WPF .just use girdview.ItemSource=property2

Comment: I am using WindowsForms and I tried to tie jsonClass.property2 to the data source but what I am getting are the properties of the ArrayList item not the actual value.

Comment: @IanSiñel does it worked ? how goes it? if you couldn't, post extra code to see what you did.

Comment: I am still stucked with this. I was able to do Steps 1 and 2 as you mentioned on your initial comment. But converting it to DataTable is where I am currently stucked. 

The `property2` is an ArrayList collection, in which this is the object I wanted to convert to DataTable without looping element per element.
I tried LINQ to query from the ArrayList but I am getting null. Here is my code:

`JsonClass jsonClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonClass>(jsonInputString);
var selected = from n in jsonClass.property2 select n;
DataTable dt = selected as DataTable;`

Comment: Thanks @Mr.AF - I did the same for WinForms but the values being retrieved are the property values not the actual values. Thank you so much for checking on this.

Comment: @IanSiñel post an photo of winform

Comment: AF please check this link [link](https://i.ibb.co/w7CktVC/Capture.jpg) as you can see on the image. it displays multiple number of rows, it matches the number of items in the array list object however what displayed are the properties of each object not the actual value.

Comment: By the way here is the code `BindingSource binding = new BindingSource();
            binding.DataSource = jsonClass.property2;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = binding;`

Comment: @IanSiñel those capacity or count are not your column names ?didn't u add them? or these column are what are shown?

Comment: those are properties of the object. Capacity is not my column name. Any of the columns in my screenshot are not.